# Want to search user messages on a public channel on the basis of userid using telethon python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using Telethon API Want to extract messages of a user from all the channels using userId. Please guide me with the procedure.
i am working more then 2 days on it but can't get any idea.
Thank you.

Comment: The [quick client reference](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html) lists the [`iter_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages) method which may be used to perform searches.